# Alternatives to "Necro-Followups"?

Tags: discussion

Hi All: I have asked a few "necro-followups" , i.e., followup questions , as comments, to questions that have been answered a few months, some times even years back. I have done this in part to avoid asking questions that are very similar to questions that have already been asked , since I thought that instead I can get an answer through the comments. I have not received many replies; I don't mean this in an accusatory way, I understand people move on with their lives and the material they are interested in, or the material that is fresh in their minds; this definitely is the case with me. What I would like to know is if there is an alternative other than asking a new question, to avoid asking something very similar to what has already been asked.

Comment: Ask a *specific* question if you need clarification, and link directly to the question or answer that you're asking about.

Comment: You can add a bounty to the question: the standard reason is "to improve detail".

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer